# Running Leroux model in WinBUGs

Tags: r, model

This may be a long shot, but I have been given some WinBUGs code to run a model with a Leroux prior. I'm interested in 'fixing' the precisions for Leroux prior and the intercept term in this model. However, I'm not very familiar with how it's specified in WinBUGs.

Here's the code (the comments are my own):

```
model{
    for (i in 1:N){
#Likelihood
   O[i]~dpois(mu[i])
   p.sig[i]<-step(s[i])
   log(mu[i])<-log(E[i])+log(theta[i])
#s is the CH, v is the UH?
   log(theta[i])<-alpha+s[i]+v[i]
   s[i]~dnorm(S[i],tau[i])
   v[i]~dnorm(0,tau.v)
#I belive inv.delta is the precision parameter for the CH term?
   tau[i]<-1/(inv.delta*(1-lam+lam*num[i]))

S[i]<-(lam/(1-lam+lam*num[i]))*sum(Ws[cum[i]+1:cum[i+1]])
  }

for (k in 1:sumNumNeigh){
    Ws[k]<-s[adj[k]]
    }

#Modify these first two terms re: fixed taus?
inv.delta~dgamma(2,1)
tau.v~dgamma(2,1)
alpha~dflat()
lam~dunif(0,1)
}
```